# Browserify to load dependencies from global scope's require instead of expecting them to be bundled up together

Tags: javascript, commonjs, browserify

I'm developing library A and library B, B depending on A.
I would like, using browserify, to bundle them up independently, so in my browser I could do:

```
var A = require("A");
var B = require("B");
```

I would like to bundle them up independently as I'm also developing library C that only depends on A and if A is included in B then it won't be accessible by C, and if A is in B and C, I've got duplicates.

So I start with browserifying library A:

```
browserify -r ./src/A.js:A -o build/A.js
```

Which works perfectly fine, I can distribute A and other people can develop their applications with it.

Then I browserify library B:

```
browserify -r ./src/B.js:B -o build/B.js
```

But I now have A two times, A being loaded independently in the browser and once again packaged with B. So I use the -i option from browserify to prevent it from being included:

```
browserify -r ./src/B.js -o build/B.js -i A
```

But then, when B requires A, it gets an empty object {} instead of the library.
The library A though is still available from the global scope by doing require("A").

I tried the externalise thing with -x but then I can't require my library from the global scope anymore.

I managed to get the behaviour that I wanted by hacking the generated output of B, forcing the module resolution to get A from a previous require, which makes me think that there can be an easy solution, but I can't find it.

I'm using browserify 2.18.1

Comment: -x, --external should be what you are looking for. See: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles

Comment: @Epeli, I tried with the --external option but it seems to have no effect as A is still in B. I tried by giving the module name:

`browserify -x A -r ./src/B.js:B -o build/B.js`

or by pointing to the file:

`browserify -x node_modules/A/A.js -r ./src/B.js:B -o build/B.js`

Any idea what -x can accept as a valid input?

my problem seems to relate to this issue on [browserify's GitHub](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/404)

Comment: afaik it should accept path to a js-file and a module name.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of looking at it :

- Think of B like jquery-ui and A as jquery.
  It's upto the users to include the jquery into the DOM, if they wish to use jquery-ui.
  So while building B do not require A at all.
- Document the fact that B has A built into it. The users who use B should simply not include A at all. In this scenario - you obviously need to require A and bundle up B with A together.
- In general if you have 2 browserified bundles, with common parts, that are being imported in the *SAME* page then you have already fallen into the problem of bundle organization/dependency, what components go in what etc. Something in the basics of that needs to be reviewed/changed